How to keep file and folder permissions and ownership in linux filesystem?
I'm working with a ubuntu webserver and often I need to load files in apache folder. Usually I use an SFTP client like filezilla or mobaterm through an SSH session.
Everytime I need to run chown and chmod command to restore the ownsership and permissions to file and folders because apache doesn't have permission to read my user's files.
Is there any way to force a file creation to take specific permission and ownership or everybody in my situation run chown/chmod every after every upload?

You can run a command to set the file permissions mask on the folder. I think it’s umask or something similar.

in combination with umask I've used setGID to automatically set the owner-group of new child items to address theses kinds of issues, though grawity's answer is definitely the better approach.

Use setfacl to add the Apache user to the files' access list. Specifically, also add it to both the effective list and to the default access list for directories, so that all newly created files will inherit that list.
setfacl -R -m u:httpd:rX ~/public_html
setfacl -R -m d:u:httpd:rX ~/public_html

